# Migrated question has no tags

Tags: bug, tagging, migration

I just noticed a question that was migrated from physics to math: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/906188/101979

When it arrived on the math site, it appeared to have no tags. I assume that the tags used on the physics site didn't exist on the math site. It seems strange that a question can exist with no tags.

Is this a bug? A feature? Not worth worrying about?

Comment: I just looked at it again, and it appears to have the tag "integration". I don't know if I just didn't see it before (because tag formatting is different on math site) or whether it just got added...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/132139/revisions) of this question on Physics shows it had the tag [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) from the beginning.

Maybe you did not notice it at first.

Comment: You must be right - would you suggest that I delete my question? Strange though that the `homework` tag (which was added in rev 2) disappeared during the migration. What would have happened if the only tags used did not exist on the new site? Would they be created by the process of migration?

Comment: @Floris Math.SE no longer has the (homework) tag, so it got removed. When none of the tags exist on the target site, migration fails - the question gets simply closed. Exception: if migration was initiated by a mod, it goes through and the question gets special tag (untagged) on the target site.

Comment: [You seem to have forgotten.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16546/definition-of-duplicate#comment60742_16546) No biggie.